# Injecting bean for Private static inner class

Tags: java, spring

Let say I have a private static inner class. 
How can I autowire it inside it's parent class?

Autowiring a public inner class is possible. But I'm unable to find a way to Autowire a private inner class.

```
public class Parent {

@Autowire
private InnerChild innerChild;

private static class InnerChild {

}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    @Component
    public class Parent {

        @Autowired
        private InnerChild innerChild;

        @Component
        private static class InnerChild {

        }

    }
```

This way it should work, but outside of its parent class you can't access InnerChild private class, even if you have a public method in Parent class exporting it, because it is accessible only by Parent class.

Comment: Will the component scan even pick up on the InnerChild since it can't really instantiate it...?